# How to import jQuery from @ember/jquery

Tags: jquery, ember.js, import, ember-cli

I am trying to import `@ember/jquery` in my component.

I have installed `@ember/jquery` and `@ember/optional-features` and imported as below

```js
import $ from '@ember/jquery'
```

but I am getting the following error in my component:

> error missing module @ember/jquery

Is this the right way to import it?

https://github.com/emberjs/ember-jquery

Comment: whats in your `config/optional-features.json` file? have you restarted the ember server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module exporting jQuery is named `jquery`, not `@ember/jquery`. `@ember/jquery` is the name of the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ember/jquery)

The correct way to import `jquery` is

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Since we are importing the default export from the `jquery` module, we can name it the way we want:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'; // this will also work and we will use `$` to reference jquery
```

For this to work, you should also enable the `jquery-integration` optional feature for your ember.js app. Check your `config/optional-features.json` file and make sure it contains the following line

```
{
  "jquery-integration": true
}
```

If `config/optional-features.json` does not exist or does not contain the `jquery-integration: true` line, you can create/edit the file manually or generate it with the cli command:

```sh
ember feature:enable jquery-integration
```

Answer (score 2):

`ember-jquery` looks like it provides jQuery as the export.  In my app I have it as `import $ from 'jquery';`. It looks like [these ember-jquery tests](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-jquery/blob/master/tests/integration/components/component-dot-dollar-test.js#L6) have it as `import jQuery from 'jquery';`.

Answer (score 1):

As of Ember 3.4.0,

```
Setting the `jquery-integration` optional feature flag to `true`, or not providing
a setting at all, has been deprecated. You must add the `@ember/optional-
features` addon and set this feature to `false`. This warning will become an error 
in Ember 4.0.0.
```

For more information, see the deprecation guide: https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_optional-feature-jquery-integration

Right way of integration jQuery to the app is

`ember install @ember/jquery`

Answer (score 0):

for future on-lookers, if you are still wanting to use jquery, this would work as well

- have ember-auto-import or embroider enabled / installed
- `yarn add jquery`
- `import $ from 'jquery';`